# Angular 5 CLI import/require custom node module

Tags: node.js, angular, webstorm, angular5, node-modules

I have a node module inside my `node_modules` directory. However, I can't figure out how to use it. The structure looks like this:

```
node_modules
|- ...
|- foo-bar
| |- dist
| |  |- css
| |     - css files here
| |  |- js
| |     - js files here
| |  |- foo-images
| |     - image files here
| |  |- index.js
| |- index.js
| |- package.json
|- ...
```

The `index.js` has this in it:

```
require('./dist/js/foo');
module.exports = 'foo';
```

So my question is how do I use it? In my `app.component.ts`, I tried putting the following code at the top:

```
import { foo } from './foo-bar';
```

But there's an error on `foo` between the curly braces saying it doesn't know what that is. When I tried `require('foo')`, I get an error saying it doesn't know what `require` is (I have Express installed).

How would I use the CSS and JavaScript functions from the node module? I'm new to Angular 5, so I'm not totally familiar with how it works. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is Front End Framework and NodeJS is server side so you will have to run any node modules on the back end server... I had a similar problem when I wanted to resize file images locally with image magick and then upload to the server. Use express to get the data from the server to the front end where you can then put your data inside '{{}}' :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful.